# Show formArray inputs in multiple columns

Tags: angular, angular-material, formarray

I have created a formArray table and now I am trying to show only 4 rows in 4 columns because I have an array that contains only 4 regions so I made a combinations of region with each other region and with itself using a nested loop with O(n)^2 complexity which gave me 16 combinations and on initializating the formarray all the input fields show up in first column which should not be the case. I need to show only 4 in each column. I am using Angular material, So how can i achieve this? Here is my html code

```
<div *ngIf="enableCombinationDirective">
  <div fxLayout="row">
      <div class="h1">Add Prices</div>
      <div [formGroup]="combinationForm">
        <div formArrayName="dest" *ngFor="let item of combinationForm.get('dest')['controls']; let i = index">
          <div fxLayout="row" class="check" fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" [formGroupName]="i" style="width: 20% !important;" apprearance="outline" fxFlex="50">
              <mat-label>{{
                combinationForm
                    .get("dest")
                    ["controls"][i].get("combinationTitle").value
            }}</mat-label>
            <input
                          matInput
                          type="number"
                          #destInput
                          formControlName="price"
                          placeholder="Enter Price"
                      />
                      <mat-checkbox
                      formControlName="isActive"
                      matSuffix
                  ></mat-checkbox>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div fxLayout="row">
          <button
              fxFlex="100"
              mat-raised-button
              color="primary"
              (click)="save()"
          >
              Save Changes
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The form works fine and i am able to fetch data from it too. here is how it looks

[image]

here is how i am initializing it

```
 createCombinations() {
    let arrayOfData = [];
    arrayOfData.push({
      volumeSlabType: this.combinationSelectionForm.value.volumeSlab, 
      serviceType: this.combinationSelectionForm.value.serviceType,
      weightSlab: this.combinationSelectionForm.value.weightSlab,
      region: this.getRegionsCombinations(this.combinationSelectionForm.value.region)
    });

    this.data = arrayOfData;
    this.data[0].region.forEach((reg, i) => {
      const fArray = this.combinationForm.get("dest") as FormArray;
      fArray.push(this.createForm(reg, i));
    });
    console.log(this.data);
  }

  createForm(dest: any, index): FormGroup {
    let group: FormGroup;

    if(this.data) {
      group = this._fb.group({
        combinationTitle: [dest.combinationTitle],
        regionId: [dest.regionId],
        price: [],
        isActive: [false],
      });
    }
    return group;
  }

  getFormData(data): FormGroup {
    return data[0].region;
  }

  getRegionsCombinations(region) {
    let selectedRegion: IRegion[] = this.regions.filter((data) => data.id === region);
    let regionCombination = [];
    this.regions.forEach((region) => {
      this.regions.forEach((rData) => {
        regionCombination.push({
          combinationTitle: `${region.name} - ${rData.name}`,
          regionId: rData.id,
          price: 0
        });
      });
    });
    return regionCombination;
  }
```

Comment: or how can i create a simple table of 4*4 in this form with 4 columns and and each column must contain 4 rows

Comment: Use NgModel instead of Form Array it's much more easy.

Comment: @JohnPeters ngModel might be easier but currently the issue is with the layout of form that i need to change. Can you help me out?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize it was a layout issue. To fix use Html Grid with grid-template-colomns mark up.

Comment: @JohnPeters I am using angular material with flex css. What i need to do is that after each 4 textboxes i want the next 4 boxes in next column on the right side and not in a straight line like they are currently showing up. I am not a CSS ninja so little help with the code will help me a lot

Comment: Sorry I don't use Flex box any longer nor give advice on it.